# JAVA postrgresql insert String[] to text[] postrgresql cell

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to make item's images names storage in postgresql DB.

This is my query:

```
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();                
    String queryString = "INSERT INTO goods (item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_images, item_price) " +
                                "VALUES ("+item.title.trim()+
                        "\',\'"+item.descr.trim()+
                        "\',\'"+item.email.trim()+
                        "\',\'"+item.phone+
                        "\',"+item.images+
                        ","+item.price+");";
int rowsUpdated = st.executeUpdate(queryString);
```

'item.images' defined as string array in model `public String images[];` 
it is receives a value from JSON post, which is looks like this:
`"images":["6307839405_3wefb6ef051_o.jpg","8715662693_1c41ewf6f7d_o.jpg","15wef131f4574e383fb46b68.jpg"],"`

**item_images** in DB defined as a 'text[]' array column.

So, i putting String array into the text[] column. Looks like should work?

But i`m getting this error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
  Position: 189
```

So, if the problem is in the way how i do it - how do i properly need store this array in DB?

Comment: 1) An `INSERT` is not a query. 2) Don't build SQL by adding strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is not to build you SQL statements through concatenation of strings as you are doing. I would use the PreparedStatement class that brings methods to deal with so many different types, as arrays, and it brings additional benefits as protection from value injections from evil users.

For instance, your code will be like:

```
PreparedStatement statement=DataBaseConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO goods (item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_images, item_price)
        VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )");
int index=1;
statement.setString(index++,item.title.trim());
statement.setString(index++,item.descr.trim());
statement.setString(index++,+item.email.trim());
statement.setString(index++,item.phone); //Assuming it is a String
statement.setArray(index++,item.images);
statement.setDouble(index++,item.price); //Assuming it is a Double
int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate()
```

I hope it helps,
Cris.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! looks like usefull option.

BTW, I'm getting a error in here `statement.setArray(index++,item.images);`

`Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String[]', required: 'java.sql.Array`

how do i transef String[] there?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that! I think it was like `statement.setArray(index++, connection.createArrayOf("text", item.images))`

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` for arrays in Postgres has different syntax. Please [see the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT).

Your result query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO goods ... ["6307839405_3wefb6ef051_o.jpg","8715662693_1c41ewf6f7d_o.jpg","15wef131f4574e383fb46b68.jpg"]
```

but should be:

```
INSERT INTO goods ... '{"6307839405_3wefb6ef051_o.jpg","8715662693_1c41ewf6f7d_o.jpg","15wef131f4574e383fb46b68.jpg"}'
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO goods ... ARRAY['6307839405_3wefb6ef051_o.jpg','8715662693_1c41ewf6f7d_o.jpg','15wef131f4574e383fb46b68.jpg']
```

So you can change your code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();                
String queryString = "INSERT INTO goods (item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_images, item_price) " +
                                "VALUES ("+item.title.trim()+
                        "\',\'"+item.descr.trim()+
                        "\',\'"+item.email.trim()+
                        "\',\'"+item.phone+
                        "\',ARRAY"+item.images.replaceAll("\"", "'")+
                        ","+item.price+");";
int rowsUpdated = st.executeUpdate(queryString);
```